# Android Design - GLsurfaceview render class triggering new activity

Tags: android

I have a general question that i have encountered already a couple of times.
When we build a view with Surfaceview or  GLsurfaceview we have would have the following classes (in the case of opengl)  :

Main activity class - that will have the render and GLsurfaceview.
GLsurfaceview class - that will be set to have a render class.
Render class - that will render the draw.

My question is, if we have a an event that happened in the render class and we want to call a new activity, what do we do ?

I always solve it by passing the Main activity class down to the rendering class and then if i need something to happen in the main activity i call MainActivity.Equels with null and in there i implement what ever i need.
Is there any nicer or more elegant way of doing it ? even design wise ?
Thanks.

Comment: I would take observer -approach. You can pass an observer to renderer and use it pretty much the same way you're using MainActivity at the moment. But design wise I find this more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

since the view always resides in the activity , use the observer pattern (commonly called "listener" in the java language) that you can set inside the activity (use the same approach used for other views , like the button.setOnClickListener) .

of course , if you have multiple threads running for your view , you should use a handler to pass the events , so that they will only run on the ui thread .

so, in short, the solution would be to extend the GLsurfaceview and add listeners functions for it .